# What should I say what you are doing or what are you doing to make a statement or declaration?

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion

What should I say "what you are doing" or "what are you doing" to a statement or declaration?

Let's say I'm on Facebook and I want to post something like "comment what you are doing". Is it correct or should I post "comment what are you doing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal word order is subject-verb-object

> you are doing [something].

When you ask a question, you invert the order of the subject and verb:

> What are you doing?

if you use "what" and it's not a question, "what" is a relative pronoun: it "relates" the first clause to the second clause, acting as object in the first clause and either subject or object of the second clause.

The relative pronoun has to between the first clause and the second clause, but otherwise the word order in the second clause is normal:

> Describe [object of clause 1]
>
> you are doing [object of clause 2]
>
> Describe [what] you are doing.

Comment: So. comment, what you are doing is correct in this case to tell my friends to comment whatever they are doing, am I correct?

Comment: Either "Describe what you are doing" or "Comment **on** what you are doing".

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying and for pointing out a missing preposition.